# What is the difference between sandboxed and farm solution in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am new to SharePoint 2010. What is the main difference between sandbox and farm solution. Can you give me 5 differences to remember. I googled, but there is lot of matter to understand. As a start up guy, i want to know the basic difference.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Farm Solution: 
Farm solutions, which are hosted in the IIS worker process (W3WP.exe), run code that can affect the whole farm. When you debug a SharePoint project whose Sandboxed Solution property is set.

Sandbox solution:
Sandboxed solutions, which are hosted in the SharePoint user code solution worker process (SPUCWorkerProcess.exe), run code that can only affect the site collection of the solution. Because sandboxed solutions do not run in the IIS worker process, neither the IIS application pool nor the IIS server must restart. Visual Studio attaches the debugger to the SPUCWorkerProcess process that the SPUserCodeV4 service in SharePoint automatically triggers and controls. It is not necessary for the SPUCWorkerProcess process to recycle to load the latest version of the solution.

For more please refere this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee361616.aspx)

You can also refere this to know sandbox solutions [goodlink](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2009-11-Top_10_things_to_consider_when_writing_SandBoxed_Solutions.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Farm Solutions:

- Farm solutions are hosted in the IIS worker process (W3WP.exe).
- If you run any code in farm solution the whole farm will got affected.
- If you deploy any feature or retract any feature the whole application pool got recycled.
- Since they are scoped as farm level, they have full trust access to all the resources.
- When the Sand boxed Solution property is set to False, selecting Build\Deploy will deploy the solution to the Farm Solution Gallery.

Sand boxed Solution:

- Sand boxed solutions are hosted in the SharePoint user code solution worker process (SPUCWorkerProcess.exe).

try to this link
- The process runs under a CAS policy that restricts programmatic access to any resource outside the sandbox.
- So it never restart the IIS application pool.
- If you run any code it will affect only the site collection of the solution.
- Helpful if you have shared hosting.
- When the Sandboxed Solution property is set to True, selecting Build\Deploy Solution deploys the solution to the site collection Solution Gallery.

One major difference in the deployment is Farm solutions are installed and deployed. Sandboxed solutions are uploaded and activated.

This Link http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/differences-between-sandboxed-and-farm-solutions-i-66.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Farm solutions, which are hosted in the IIS worker process (W3WP.exe), run code that **can affect the whole farm**. 
Sandboxed solutions, which are hosted in the SharePoint user code solution worker process (SPUCWorkerProcess.exe), run code that **can only affect the site collection of the solution**. 
(from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee361616.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

One major difference is we can't create Aplication pages in Sandbox solutions.Beacuse Application pages are stored in the `14\TEMPLATES\_LAYOUTS` and when we deploy as sandbox we dont have permissions to the physical folder.

- Also we cant create VISUAL web parts in Sandbox soultions.
- We cant use code to connect to the external web services or to database in the sandbox soltion
- Farm solutions are installed and deployed. Sandboxed solutions are uploaded and activated.

Comment: Says here that visual web parts are ok: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231562.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Normally we are using Sandbox solution for Online sharepoint such as office365. In this case user will get a solution to work with, but not the Physical system folders. So we cant give any images or contents into the Layout folder(it is restricted). And the main thing is We couldn't able to use some SP-class features in the Sandbox solution(which can be get the information about other farm solutions and server information). Thus farm solution is restricting this SP classes, system folders along with SPUCWorkerProcess process.

We can **create the Visual Webparts as Sandbox solutions in 2013** but we have to make sure about the classes and we never want to use the layout folders etc.

Answer (score 0):

Farm Solutions properties:

- Farm solutions are hosted in the IIS worker process (W3WP.exe).
- If you run any code in farm solution the whole farm will got affected.
- If you deploy any feature or retract any feature the whole application pool got recycled.

Since they are scoped as farm level, they have full trust access to all the resources.

When the Sand boxed Solution property is set to False, selecting Build\Deploy will deploy the solution to the Farm Solution Gallery.

Answer (score -1):

One major difference is we can't create Aplication pages in Sandbox solutions.Beacuse Application pages are stored in the 14\TEMPLATES_LAYOUTS and when we deploy as sandbox we dont have permissions to the physical folder.

- Also we cant create VISUAL web parts in Sandbox soultions.
- We cant use code to connect to the external web services or to database in the sandbox soltion
- Farm solutions are installed and deployed. Sandboxed solutions are uploaded and activated.

Farm solutions, which are hosted in the IIS worker process (W3WP.exe), run code that can affect the whole farm. 
Sandboxed solutions, which are hosted in the SharePoint user code solution worker process (SPUCWorkerProcess.exe), run code that can only affect the site collection of the solution.

Answer (score -2):

Please look the website that contains more details about the Farm Solutions and Sandbox Solution details :

http://www.techcontents.com/uncategorized/difference-farm-solutions-sandbox-solutions-sharepoint-2010/