# what is difference between sandbox solution and farm solution in sharepoint 2010

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I am new to SharePoint 2010, I want to know what is the difference between Sandbox solution and farm solution.
I googled it and I find the difference below

Farm solutions are are hosted in the IIS worker process (W3WP.exe),

Sandboxed solutions are hosted in the SharePoint user code solution worker process (SPUCWorkerProcess.exe).

However I can not understand how to run code that can affect the whole farm if I select 'farm solution'.
I want to have an example demonstrating this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546270/what-is-the-difference-between-sandboxed-and-farm-solution-in-sp2010

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, but i need to example to demonstrate how run cod can affect whole farm when i selected farm solution ???
just this my question